# When I request from instagram user info it's return only user name

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I use this python [library](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram):

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = "Access Token"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
user_info = api.user(user_id)
print user_info
```

I couldn't receive this answer:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}
```

how i could retrive bio, followers count an etc. info? thankyou

Comment: So, what do you receive exactly? With HTTP status code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You actually are receiving the entire response, but the Python version of the Instagram API client is returning instances of their `User` class (inherits from the `ApiModel` class).

You can get all the data you need by accessing those properties individually:

```
user = api.user('1574083')
print user.username
print user.full_name
print user.profile_picture
print user.bio
print user.website
print user.counts
```

Which prints:

```
snoopdogg
snoopdogg
http://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-19/11186934_976841435684008_1692889037_a.jpg
Get BUSH now!
http://smarturl.it/BushAlbum
{u'media': 19019, u'followed_by': 6746636, u'follows': 1707}
```

This is deceptive because if you just print the `user` you will only see `User: snoopdogg`. In Python its possible to overwrite a lot of methods that wouldn't be allowed in other languages. Specifically here they've overwritten `__str__`, `__repr__`, and `__unicode__` which are all used to convert objects to string-type objects for printing.

It is my understanding that `__str__` and `__unicode__` should be the "pretty" version, while `__repr__` should show you (if possible) how you can reconstruct the object. They've done a pretty weak job of accomplishing either goal, but it is arguably better than the default representation of an object, which would be something like `<instagram.models.User object at 0xf8c5a750>`.

Comment: How can you see the list of properties that are accessible?

Comment: In Python there is built-in function, `dir`, that returns a list of valid attributes for the argument (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir).
For this case if I run `print dir(user)` I get a list including the fields 'bio', 'counts', 'full_name', 'id', 'object_from_dictionary', 'profile_picture', 'username', 'website' (along with a bunch of built-in functions like `__str__` and `__dict__`).